# Solving matrix equation involving sum of trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, trace

Define a symmetic matrix $\Theta_j\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}, \forall j \in \{1,2,\cdots,M\}$, symmetic matrices $A,S\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$, scalar $\rho\in \mathbb R_+$, and scalar $c_{i,j} \in \mathbb R, \forall i \in \{1,2,\cdots,N\}, \forall j \in \{1,2,\cdots,M\}$. We have

$$
A   +    
{\rho} \sum\limits_{i=1}^N \sum\limits_{j=1}^{M} \left({\Theta_j}\left(\operatorname{Tr}\left({\Theta_j} X \right) + {c_{i,j}} \right) \right)  
+ 2\left(X^\top - S\right) = 0.
$$

Note that the matrices $\Theta_j$ are not positive definite. I wonder how to calculate $X\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$.

Comment: Are $\Theta_j$ defined for $j=1,\dots,N$ or for $j=1,\dots,M$? Actually the problem is a system of $n^2$ linear equations on entries of $X$, so basically it requires only to write it in form of $\mathbb R^{n^2 \times n^2}$ matrix and $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ right hand side.

Comment: Sorry, $\Theta_j$ is defined for $j=\{1,2,\cdots,M\}$.

Comment: Using both $N$ and $n$ for scalars is confusing.

Comment: You don't need the $c_{ij}$. They only confuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's rearrange terms and separate knowns from unknowns:
$$
2 X^\top + \rho \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^M \Theta_j \operatorname{Tr}(\Theta_j X) = 
2 S - A - \rho \sum_{j=1}^M \Theta_j \sum_{i=1}^N c_{i,j}
$$
It is clear now that summation by $i$ is not necessary. Let $d_j = \sum_{i=1}^N c_{i,j}$.
$$
2X^\top + \rho N \sum_{j=1}^M \Theta_j \operatorname{Tr}(\Theta_j X) = 2S - A - \rho \sum_{j=1}^M d_j \Theta_j
$$
The right hand side is known, so let's denote is as $R \equiv 2S - A - \rho \sum_{j=1}^M d_j \Theta_j$.

Let's simplify further by replacing $\operatorname{Tr}(\Theta_j X)$ by $\operatorname{Tr}(X^\top\Theta_j^\top)$. Since $\Theta_j$ are symmetric, $\operatorname{Tr}(X^\top\Theta_j^\top) = \operatorname{Tr}(X^\top\Theta_j)$. After that only $X^\top$ remains in the equation
$$
2X^\top + \rho N \sum_{j=1}^M \Theta_j \operatorname{Tr}(X^\top \Theta_j) = R.
$$
Now let's apply the [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) to the both sides:
$$
2 \operatorname{vec}(X^\top) + \rho N \sum_{j=1}^M \operatorname{vec}
(\Theta_j) \operatorname{Tr}(X^\top \Theta_j)
=
\operatorname{vec}(R).
$$
Using the property $\operatorname{Tr}(AB) = \operatorname{vec}(A)^\top \operatorname{vec}(B) 
= \operatorname{vec}(B)^\top \operatorname{vec}(A)$ we obtain
$$
2 \operatorname{vec}(X^\top) + \rho N \sum_{j=1}^M \operatorname{vec}
(\Theta_j) \operatorname{vec}(\Theta_j)^\top \operatorname{vec}(X^\top)
=
\operatorname{vec}(R).
$$
Finally the equation can be written as a system of linear equations:
$$
\left[
2 I + \rho N \sum_{j=1}^M \operatorname{vec}
(\Theta_j) \operatorname{vec}(\Theta_j)^\top
\right]
\operatorname{vec}(X^\top)
=
\operatorname{vec}(R).
$$
The matrix of the system is symmetric and positive definite.

Here is a [small python implemetation](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/gist.githubusercontent.com/uranix/2ff1175776137eeca27d1a994e893c72/raw/05318354ea71606a5303ad2c9a56d08287264e1b/Q3799415.ipynb) of the method.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\bb{\mathbb}$
Start by taking the transpose of the equation
$$\eqalign{
(2S^T - A^T)
 &= 2X + \rho\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^M\Theta_j{\rm Tr}({\Theta_j} X) + \Theta_j\,{C_{ij}} \tag{1} \\
}$$
Define the vectors $\,b_j={\rm vec}(\Theta_j)$ and collect them into
the columns of a matrix
$$\eqalign{
 B &= \big[b_1\;b_2\;\ldots\;b_M\big] \in {\bb R}^{n^2\times M} \\
 b_j &= Be_j \\
}$$
where $\{e_j\}$ denote the standard basis vectors for $\bb R^M$ and, for future reference, 
let ${\tt1}\in\bb R^N$ denote the all-ones vector.

[Vectorizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) Equation $(1)$ yields
$$\eqalign{
(2Ks - Ka)
  &= 2x + N\rho\sum_j b_jb_j^Tx + \rho\sum_i\sum_j {\tt1}_iC_{ij}b_j \\
(2Ks - Ka)
  &= 2x + N\rho BB^Tx + \rho BC^T{\tt1} \\
\big(2I+N\rho BB^T\big)x &= \big(2Ks-Ka-\rho BC^T{\tt1}\big) \\
x &= \big(2I+N\rho BB^T\big)^{-1}\big(2Ks-Ka-\rho BC^T{\tt1}\big) \\
}$$
where $K$ is the [Commutation Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) used to vectorize the transpose of a matrix and
$$a={\rm vec}(A),\quad s={\rm vec}(S),\quad x={\rm vec}(X)$$

The remaining step is to reshape the solution vector $(x)$ into a matrix $(X)$.